# Defining some newcommand with \href, Problems of ##

Tags: hyperref

I want to set a new command which aims at using href (from hyperref package) but by providing some hypertarget as argument of the new command for a specific pdf.

Classical use of hypperref and href is :
In first document A, I put some hypertarget :

```
\hypertarget{fileAhypertarget}{Should come to this}
```

In the second document B, I make a reference to hypertarget of document FileA.pdf

```
\href{fileA.pdf#fileAhypertarget}{Let's go to file A!}
```

Please notice that syntax of href for url in pdf use a # symbol

It works, but now I want to define a command of this type

```
\newcommand{\myhref}[2]{\href{fileA.pdf##1}{#2}}
```

But it does not work as # symbol of href command enters in conflict with `#` symbol of arguments of `\newcommand`.

Have you any idea, I try different syntax, \protect and thought to \expandafter but I failed.

If you have any idea, Thanks a lot

Comment: you need `##` for the `#`  and `#1` for the argument, so 3 `#`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Did you try?

Comment: @egreg no I went home:-) (I thought hyperref rescanned it, I guess not:-)

Answer (score 5):

You need that LaTeX sees a “stringified” `#`; here's a way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begingroup\lccode`?=`# \lowercase{\endgroup
  \newcommand{\myhref}[2]{\href{fileA.pdf?#1}{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
\myhref{fileAhypertarget}{Let's go}
\end{document}
```

Of course you lose the special treatment `\href` does to special characters, but it's not a problem if argument `#1` has none of them.