# How to define a href-like command?

Tags: macros, errors, hyperref, color, links

I'm trying to make an `\href`-like command that will color its text. The one I made breaks when the URL has `#`. I tried the solution in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171847/defining-some-newcommand-with-href-problems-of), but it still doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\colorlet{linkcolor}{green!20!black}

\begingroup\lccode`?=`# \lowercase{\endgroup
\newcommand*{\linc}[2]{\href{#1}{\textcolor{linkcolor}{#2}}}%link-colored
}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171847/defining-some-newcommand-with-href-problems-of

\begin{document}
\linc{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX.SE}%Causes no errors

\linc{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Typesetting_system}{\LaTeX\ article}%Can't compile anymore
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to escape `#` from the link and not worry about it, here is a lualatex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
%\colorlet{linkcolor}{green!20!black}
\colorlet{linkcolor}{red} %changed to red to make it more clear

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function linc(arg1,arg2)
   tex.print("\\href{"..arg1.."}{".."\\textcolor{linkcolor}{"..arg2.."}}");
end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand*{\linc}[2]{\luadirect{ linc("\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}",
                                       "\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}")}}

\begin{document}    
\linc{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX.SE}%Causes no errors

\linc{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Typesetting_system}{\LaTeX\ article}%no errors now
\end{document}
```

compile with `lualatex foo.tex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Strange that it worked as is. I was going to replace the `#` to `\#` inside lua using subs, so that the caller do not have to worry about it, but it turned out not to be needed!

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to escape the `#` symbol of `\linc`'s first argument.
The following will work without error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\colorlet{linkcolor}{green!20!black}

\newcommand{\linc}[2]{\href{#1}{\textcolor{linkcolor}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\linc{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX.SE}%Causes no errors

\linc{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX\#Typesetting_system}{\LaTeX\ article}%Can't compile anymore
\end{document}
```